# Siunitx S column with line break

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I have a table with many `S` columns of the `siunitx` package containing mean and errors. The table is to wide for the page width when the mean and error are typed in one line. However breaking a line after the `+-` sign would work, but the decimal alignment should also be present.

Is it possible to define a fixed length for a `S` column of the `siunitx` package and thus get line breaks like in the `p` column?

Edit:
The mean could take the following forms `xx.x` ; `x.x` ; `x` and `xx`.
The errors could take the following forms `xx.x` ; `x.x` ; `x` and `xx`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \sisetup{ table-number-alignment=center,
    table-figures-uncertainty=1,
          separate-uncertainty=true,
          table-figures-integer = 2,
          table-figures-decimal = 1}
    \caption{Caption}
            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{8}{S}}
            \toprule
                  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C1}}               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C2}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C3}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C4}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C5}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C6}    
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C7}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C8}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C9}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C10}       \\
                \midrule
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z1} & XY & 10.2 \pm 0.4 & 20.2 \pm 12.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 22.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4         \\
                                                             & YZ & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 12.4       \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){3-10}
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z2} & XY & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 30.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4        \\
                                                             & YZ & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4        \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have also read the manual of **PgfplotsTable**. It seems uncommon to have errors/uncertainties appear on a second line. Indeed **siunitx** provides something like **10.2[4]** to express uncertainties tightly. At worse case, you can always rearrange your input so data and uncertainties form two individual lines.

Comment: @Symbol1 The problem is if I put e.g. `10.2 \pm` in the first line and `0.4` in the second line I get the following error: `siunitx error: "misplaced-sign-token" Misplaced sign token '10.2\pm '. [...] Sign tokens can only come at the beginning of a number.` If I put the `\pm` in the second line the spacing between this symbol and the number is missing. Also I think the `\pm` symbol should be in the first line.

Comment: Well that error is because **siunitx** consider `\pm` different, as a sign-token to be precise. Override it by `\sisetup{input-signs=,input-symbols=\pm}`. If you are not satisfied with the spacing, try `\def\pm{\kern1pt\mathchar"2206}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something of a hack, certainly not for general use, and relies on the fact that all errors take the same form, in this case, `x.x` (other cases discussed at end)).  I present two variants, with the `\pm` on the 2nd row, and with the `\pm` on the 1st row.

It accomplishes its goal by redefining `\pm` to create a stack.  The number of arguments in `\pmhelp` should be 1 plus the number of digits in the error term (including the point as a digit).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\let\svpm\pm
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,booktabs,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\pm{\pmhelp}
% \pm on 2nd line
\def\pmhelp#1#2#3#4{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{{}\svpm #1#2#3#4\strut}}}
% \pm on 1st line
\def\altpmhelp#1#2#3#4{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{#1#2#3#4\strut}}\svpm{}\kern-8pt}
\begin{document}

\def\mktb{%
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \sisetup{ table-number-alignment=center,
    table-figures-uncertainty=1,
          separate-uncertainty=true,
          table-figures-integer = 2,
          table-figures-decimal = 1}
    \caption{Caption}
            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{8}{S}}
            \toprule
                  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C1}}               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C2}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C3}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C4}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C5}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C6}    
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C7}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C8}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C9}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C10}       \\
                \midrule
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z1} & XY & 10.2 \pm 0.4 & 20.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4       \\
                                                             & YZ & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4        \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){3-10}
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z2} & XY & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 30.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4        \\
                                                             & YZ & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4 & 1.2 \pm 2.4        \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}}
\mktb
\let\pmhelp\altpmhelp
\mktb
\let\pm\svpm
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As addressed in a comment, the error form `x.xx` can be addressed with a slight modification from above.

If `table-figures-decimal` is set equal to 2, and if all data entries finish with the same format: `\pm x.xx`, then here are the revised definitions that will work:

```
% \pm on 2nd line 
\def\pmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}%
  \llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{{}\svpm #1#2#3#4#5\strut}}} 
% \pm on 1st line 
\def\altpmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}%
  \llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{#1#2#3#4‌​#5\strut}}\svpm{}\kern-8pt}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

---

For an error form `xx.x`, the approach was much more problematic, for reasons I don't understand.  While I would have expected `table-figures-decimal` to be set to 1 for this case, that only resulted in errors using the stacking approach employed.  I was forced to set `table-figures-decimal` equal to 2, and then make manual spacing corrections to compensate.  Very strange.  But here is the MWE that worked for that:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\let\svpm\pm
\usepackage{siunitx,multirow,booktabs,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\pm{\pmhelp}
% \pm on 2nd line
\def\pmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder{}{{}\svpm #1#2#3#4#5\strut\,~}}}
% \pm on 1st line
\def\altpmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{#1#2#3#4#5\strut\,~}}\kern-5pt\svpm{}}
\begin{document}

\def\mktb{%
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \sisetup{ table-number-alignment=center,
    table-figures-uncertainty=1,
          separate-uncertainty=true,
          table-figures-integer = 2,
          table-figures-decimal = 2}
    \caption{Caption}
            \begin{tabular}{*{2}{c} *{8}{S}}
            \toprule
                  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C1}}               & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{C2}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C3}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C4}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C5}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C6}    
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C7}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C8}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C9}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C10}       \\
                \midrule
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z1} & XY & 10.2 \pm 22.4 & 20.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4       \\
                                                             & YZ & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4        \\
                    \cmidrule(lr){3-10}
                    \multirow{2}{*}{Z2} & XY & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 30.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4        \\
                                                             & YZ & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4 & 31.2 \pm 22.4        \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\mktb
\let\pmhelp\altpmhelp
\mktb
\let\pm\svpm
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you amazing solution. One additional question: I don't know exactly what you mean with your second paragraph. I should have mentioned in the MWE that some of the errors could take the form `xx.x` (now corrected). So I tried your solution with an added `#5` but this gives me an error. Could you please tell me what I have to change?

Comment: @user2653422 Keep in mind this solution is very *ad hoc*.  But **if** `table-figures-decimal` is set equal to `2`, and if *all* data entries finish with the same format: `\pm x.xx`, then here are the revised definitions: `% \pm on 2nd line
\def\pmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{{}\svpm #1#2#3#4#5\strut}}}
% \pm on 1st line
\def\altpmhelp#1#2#3#4#5{\def\stackalignment{r}\llap{\stackunder[1pt]{}{#1#2#3#4#5\strut}}\svpm{}\kern-8pt}`

Comment: Ok that works for `x.xx` but I also need it for `xx.x`. That are also 4 digits plus the additional one, but in that case I get errors if I add the fifth parameter `#5`.

Comment: @user2653422 I have edited to show three different cases.  Indeed, the `x.xx` case acted very strangely, requiring an adaptation that was not to my liking, but it may suffice.