# Overfull hbox with S column from siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

Based on a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/256442/45570) I created the MWE given below. What I don't understand is that I get three `Overfull \hbox (9.9778pt to wide)` warnings. Where do they come from as they don't appear in the final over/underfull warnings and what to change to get rid of them?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \def\pm{\kern2.2pt\mathchar"2206}
    \newlength{\tabcolseptemp}
  \setlength{\tabcolseptemp}{\widthof{$\pm$}}
    \addtolength{\tabcolseptemp}{10pt}
    \centering
    \sisetup{
        table-figures-integer = 1,
        table-figures-decimal = 1,
        table-number-alignment = center,
        output-decimal-marker = {,},
        input-signs=,input-symbols=\pm
    }
            \begin{tabular}{S[table-figures-integer = 1,table-figures-decimal = 1] @{\hskip \tabcolseptemp} S[table-figures-integer = 2,table-figures-decimal = 1] @{\hskip \tabcolseptemp} S[table-figures-integer = 2,table-figures-decimal = 1]}
            \toprule
                     \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$A$}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$B$}}
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$C$}}        \\
                \midrule
                1.5 \pm  & 12.0 \pm  & 15.0 \pm          \\  1.0 & 2.0 & 3.0         \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler approach:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\tpm}{\ensuremath{\,\pm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp]

\centering

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,},
}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.1,table-space-text-post=\tpm]
  S[table-format=2.1,table-space-text-post=\tpm]
  S[table-format=2.1,table-space-text-post=\tpm]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$A$}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$B$}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\boldmath{$C$}} \\
\midrule
1.5 \tpm & 12.0 \tpm & 15.0 \tpm \\
1.0      &  2.0      &  3.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]